# REST Url ID Placement for Resources with Collections

Tags: rest, restful-url

Is this a good structure for REST URLs?

Assuming:

```
GET /account  <- get list of accounts
GET /account/1234 <- get account 1234
```

etc.

If the account resource has a collection that I want to interface, is this a good idea?

```
GET /account/1234/note <- get notes for account 1234
POST /account/1234/note <- add note to account 1234
DELETE /account/1234/note/321 <- delete note 321 on account 1234
```

Especially that last one gives me pause; typically I wouldn't require both the entity ID and the parent ID when deleting.

Or maybe something like this would be better?

```
GET /account-note/1234 <- get notes for account 1234
POST /account-note/1234 <- add note to account 1234
DELETE /account-note/321 <- delete note 321 on account 1234 (b/c note 321 is on account 1234)
```

But then I'd end up with a pretty shallow URL set.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referenced this question in my comments on another question and between the feedback I got there and my own research this is what I've come up with.

Firstly, the question is sort of flawed. RESTful APIs, or to use the perferable term Hypermedia APIs should include the urls of related actions so that the interface is discoverable and changes won't break existing clients, therefore the exact structure has significantly less importance than I was placing on it, these can be changed later.

Secondly, the note in the example will be retrieved as part of an account query, maybe something like this:

```
<account>
   ...
   <notes>
      <note>
         ...
         <link href="/account-note/123" rel="note">
      </note>
   </notes>
</account>
```

The client will never be assembling urls to the account on their own, the client will use the link provided. Since the note ID is globally unique in this case, there is no need to include the key twice. Hence the answer to the question is no, the first example is not a good REST url structure, the second one is better. (Although still maybe not the best...)

Comment: Sorry I disagree. Besides good points raised by @Ben, your second way forces the client to parse the output of an account query before client can access notes. Hence double the latency.

Comment: This is a principle of HATEOAS, that the response of a RESTful operation return URLs of supported operations on the resource. There are many ways to provide the URLs, either using a proprietary protocol (which IMHO is not so useful) or a defined format like Hypermtext Application Language (HAL). There is really no reason for concern about client parsing--work performed on client will of course scale 1:1 as clients are added, and reading a URL isn't much work and the additional bandwidth is a small price to pay for the architectural advantages. [continued]

Comment: It is kind of a pain right now to do this the 'right' way, because few (none?) of the frameworks support anything like HAL. Also REST is just a tool, it is just one way to do things, if you've got a case where REST carries low benefits (one example that jumps to mind would be a scenario where you own both client and server, the ratio of clients to servers is low, and throughput perform is very important--and perhaps you're running over cellular or something expensive) you are completely free to implement whatever sort of protocol you want, doesn't have to conform to any RESTful principles.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your first api. In large part, the idea of the RESTful interface is to go with the natural tree structure of the web, and your first approach is in keeping with that. It's also going to be a structure that does the API's job of abstracting away implicit constraints of your datastore, because the second approach implicitly assumes that the id of note is globally unique. This may be true now, and will probably remain true, but it's also exactly the kind of bug that suddenly appears with disastrous consequences when, down the line, some kind of major db change happens.

I'd go with your first scheme. It's a familiar rest pattern, it's intuitive, and it's not going to blow up in a weird way down the line. Also, in response to @Corwin01 minimize the query params--they're not so RESTful.

Answer (score -1):

Mind you, my experience is with JAX-RS and Jersey, so I'm not sure what the exact differences are.

However, this is what I would do:

```
    @GET
    @Path ("/account/note/{id}")
    public void displayNotes(@PathParam ("accountId") String accountId)
    {
      //do stuff
    }

    @POST
    @Path ("/account/note")
    public void addNote(@FormParam ("accountId") String accountId)
    {
      //do stuff
    }

    @POST
    @Path ("/account/note/delete")
    public void deleteNote(@FormParam ("accountId") String accountId, @FormParam ("noteId") String noteId)
    {
      //do stuff
    }
```

This way, you don't have cluttered and confusing URLs that the user doesn't need to see anyways, especially if the user tries to navigate there on their own.  Which is ok for displaying the accounts, but would confuse them for the URLs that POST, since they would get a 404 and not understand why.

Keep it simple, and just user @FormParams since the user doesn't need to see that anyways.

Comment: Totally not RESTful. You should be deleting things with the `DELETE` verb, to say the least.