# Routes for MVC 4 Web APIs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In my initial stab at creating a MVC4 Web API. I've noticed a few things about the way routes are handled that seems a little off:

- Controllers no longer ever have more than 4 actions?
- A resource that only supports one HTTP verb still gets it's very own controller?
- The route hierarchy tends to be very flat, OR
- An extremely large number of routes must be specified/maintained compared to MVC apps for humans.

I've created fairly large sites that use only two or three routes, but I'm just starting on my API and I'm up to almost a dozen. I guess APIs by their nature lend themselves to deeper URLs than websites, but this seems a little excessive.

I feel like I'm missing a namespace somewhere or a routing convention. I attribute nearly all of this to the fact that action names are no longer part of the route, just the HTTP method. Is there a way to support routes by anything other than parameter matching, controller name, and HTTP method?

Comment: *4 actions + overloads assuming GET/PUT/POST/DELETE...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the routing in Global.asax.  The default is set to:

```
           routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

But you could change it for example to use the action name:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ActionApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

For more information on custom routing in MVC WEb API look at this [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).

***Update based on comments***

Above was the answer to the question, "can I change the routing?"  The short answer is yes, but as was pointed out in another answer you may not want to and maintain a good REST API. MVC Web API with it default routing maintains the basic REST concept that you are working on resources, with the controller representing the resource.  In your other question you give the example:

```
DELETE /account/1234/note/321 <- delete note 321 on account 1234
```

Where you want to delete a note on account 1234. In this case the resource you are working on is a note.  A better representation for this would be to use query string so your API for this example would look like this:

```
DELETE /note/321?account=1234 <- delete note 321 on account 1234
```

This way you do not need to mess with the routing and it is clear that the resource being acted upon is a note with filters being used.  But I would also question whether adding this explicit filter (i.e. where clause) is necessary if the id for note is unique for the whole application and not just for a specific account.

Comment: Thanks for the additions here, this is the first REST API I've actually tried to write, and still somewhere between the "REST is like SOAP except with HTTP" stage and being comfortable with it. In my other question the id of the 'note' is globally unique, so think I'll drop the account #. I'm still under the impression that if I have an account and an account note then using "/account/note/123" is better semantically than just "/note/123" to represent the resource. There just doesn't seem to be a good way in MVC4 to created this nesting without creating a bunch of routes to maintain.

Comment: @Paul Use whatever URL structure works easily for the framework.  There is nothing wrong with `/note/123`  If you really want to be clear that it is an Account Note then maybe use `/accountnote/123`.  Urls are just identifiers, don't beat yourself up over their structure.

Comment: I agree with @DarrelMiller on his suggestion. A great resource for designing API's is the guys at Apigee [http://apigee.com/about/resources]. They have some great free videos and ebooks on developing RESTful APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The Web API is designed and tailored for RESTFull services, think of the controller as the service name.  GET/PUT/POST/DELETE are mapped to the controller action who's name contains the verb, by convention.

If you are not trying to do something RESTFull, then I would use an HTTPController instead.  As you likely noticed, you can mix them in the same project with separate routes.

Comment: I am trying to create a one, although this is my first really RESTful API. Maybe my URLs aren't structured correctly: /customer/1234/premise/456/note/789. I asked this question a few days back although I didn't really get a satisfactory answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266108/rest-url-id-placement-for-resources-with-collections/11266306#comment14812617_11266306

Comment: Web API is tailored for HTTP based APIs.  You can build RESTful systems with Web API and you can build non-REST HTTP apis.  There is nothing in Web API that pushes you in a REST direction.