# Routing in WCF REST with hierarchical resources

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, routes

I have a RESTful web service containing hierarchical resources. I want to separate these resources in different services class mapped by a global routing class (global.asax). For example,  if I had a resource hierarchy like that:

```
Book/
Book/{BookID}/Chapters/
Book/{BookID}/Chapters/{ChapterID}/
etc...
```

I could only map to one class like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Books/", new WebServiceHostFactory()
  , typeof(BookService)));
```

This works, but I have to implement all the methods in that single service. I'd much rather have multiple service class like BookService, ChapterService, etc... like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Books/", new WebServiceHostFactory()
  , typeof(BookService)));

RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Books/{BookID}/Chapters/"
  , new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ChapterService)));
```

But it doesn't work... So right now I am forced to have all my method defined in a single service. Is there a way around that or am I doomed to use this single huge service class ?

Comment: Ever considered switching to ASP.NET MVC4 Web API? It's better suited for RESTful web services, as it mostly aims for this.

Comment: It's probably what I'll have to do... Thanks for the answer !

Comment: I don't think you have to do it, but it's what I'd suggest you do to. :) Did you perhaps try to reverse the routes, adding the more deeper ones first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459596/routes-for-mvc-4-web-apis/11460097#11460097). It has to do with routing using the ASP.NET Web API (which some comments suggested using and I would also), but it also relates to developing RESTful API's in general. I would not try to show the hierarchy of your schema in the API as I think it adds to much unneeded complexity. So an example for your API would look something like this:

```
/Chapters/{ChapterID}?Book={BookID}
```

This eliminates complex routing, is easier for API users to understand, and sticks with RESTful principles.

Comment: I disagree with "is easier for API users to understand". I think this is harder to understand, especially when you have several sub-collections.

Comment: @Martin1921 Then we agree to disagree. I say it is easier to understand because it is the convention used by most other REST API's and by OData Services [http://www.odata.org/media/30002/OData.html#queryingcollections].

Comment: That's alright to me. :) But out of curiosity, in which section did you find a syntax similar to the one described here? I couldn't find anything under 10.2.3.

Comment: The whole section is on querying collections which takes the basic format of http://{Server}/{Service}/{Resource}?{query or filter}. In the example above "Book=BookID" is the filter to return only Chapters that match that query. You could argue that ChapterID is also part of the query and use the format /Chapters?Chapter={ChapterID}&Book={BookID}. This format makes it clear what resource is being acted upon (in this example Chapters) and the verb would indicate which action (i.e. GET, DELETE, POST, UPDATE).